# network manager v1.2.6 breaks openvpn connection

Tags: network-manager, suspend, openvpn

I have been having a rather serious and incredibly annoying problem on the updated version of network-manager v1.2.6 in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Trying to manually connect to my VPN provider through the network manager openvpn client fails literally any time except bootup. Every godforsaken time. Waking the computer from suspend results in the network manager 'reconnecting' but no actual internet connection. Restarting the network manager using

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

sometimes doesn't work at all and I actually have to reboot the computer for it to connect to the internet. Despite the icon showing that I'm connected, in actuality I have no internet connection and cannot load any web pages.
This issue isn't present at all on v1.2.2, which I have downgraded to and used apt-mark hold to keep it in place. Any insight or confirmation of this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue in 1.2.6.

The ticket is open here and has a high priority for it to be fixed.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1671606

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I have found the issue pertaining to dns resolution on Ubuntu 16.04.2! There is a critical bug in the package dnsmasq-base here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dnsmasq/+bug/1639776
The fix hasn't yet been applied to the current version of dnsmasq-base.

This time I have all the dependencies on 1.2.6 at their newest version and installing the patched .deb version provided by Harald Rudell fixes DNS name resolution on wakeup/suspend and with restart of the network manager, all while cooperating with openvpn. I hope this helps anyone on 16.04.2 LTS!

wget https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dnsmasq/+bug/1639776/+attachment/4780245/+files/dnsmasq-base_2.76-4ubuntu1FIX1639776ubuntu1_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i dnsmasq-base_2.76-4ubuntu1FIX1639776ubuntu1_amd64.deb

This appears to have actually worked, and is much better than using dnscrypt-proxy (which I have found to be incredibly slow) or holding back a bunch of packages.